# Unable to append collection of entries to NumPy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following numpy arrays:

```
R    = np.array([-4, -10,  0,  8, 15, 22,  3],  dtype=float)
B    = np.array([4, -10,  0,  8, 15, 5,  1],  dtype=float)
G    = np.array([0, -10,  0,  8, 15, 2,  38],  dtype=float)
```

I need to take ith element of each of these 3 arrays and append it to the ith position of another array RBG. This is how I tried doing it:

```
RBG = np.empty((7,3))

for i,c in enumerate(R):
   np.append(RBG, (R[i], B[i], G[i]) ) 

   #Only for debugging purpose.Illustrates the desired format.
   print("R={} B = {} G ={} i={}".format(R[i],B[i],G[i],i))
```

This is what gets printed:

```
R=-4.0 B = 4.0 G =0.0 i=0
R=-10.0 B = -10.0 G =-10.0 i=1
R=0.0 B = 0.0 G =0.0 i=2
R=8.0 B = 8.0 G =8.0 i=3
R=15.0 B = 15.0 G =15.0 i=4
R=22.0 B = 5.0 G =2.0 i=5
R=3.0 B = 1.0 G =38.0 i=6
```

But, on printing the resultant array, RBG:

```
[[4.4943389e-316 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]
[0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]
[0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]
[0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]
[0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]
[0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]
[0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000 0.0000000e+000]]
```

Why is this happening? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achive it like this

```py
R    = np.array([-4, -10,  0,  8, 15, 22,  3],  dtype=float)
B    = np.array([4, -10,  0,  8, 15, 5,  1],  dtype=float)
G    = np.array([0, -10,  0,  8, 15, 2,  38],  dtype=float)

RBG = np.array([R,B,G]).transpose()



print(RBG)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RBG = np.vstack((R, B, G))
L = list(["R={} B = {} G ={} i={} ".format(RBG[0, i], RBG[1, i], RBG[2, i], i) for i in range(7)])
for i in L:
    print(i)
```

output：

```
R=-4.0 B = 4.0 G =0.0 i=0 
R=-10.0 B = -10.0 G =-10.0 i=1 
R=0.0 B = 0.0 G =0.0 i=2 
R=8.0 B = 8.0 G =8.0 i=3 
R=15.0 B = 15.0 G =15.0 i=4 
R=22.0 B = 5.0 G =2.0 i=5 
R=3.0 B = 1.0 G =38.0 i=6
```